# Is there a more elegant way to apply complicated functions to meshgrid?

Tags: python, numpy, plot, visualization

My goal is to plot the function $f(x,y) = 3^{\min\{x,2\}}t_0 y$
where $t_0$
is the smallest solution of $2t^x-3t-1=0$ (it's just a MWE; I didn't check the existence of the root(s). )

I did it. But in somehow an ugly way.

My approach is to apply the function element-wise. Here is my code:

```python
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def equ(t,*data):   # 2t^x - 3t -1 
    x = data
    return 2*(t ** x) - 3*t - 1
    
def t0(t):  # call fslove to solve the equation
    return fsolve(equ, 1.5, args=(t))[0] # 1.5 is randomly choosed

xx = np.linspace(1,3,50)    # range of x
yy = np.linspace(1,3,50)    # range of y
ff = [] # the value of f at each (x, y)

# compute the value of f element-wise
for x in xx:
    for y in yy:
        f = (3 ** np.minimum(x, 2)) * t0(x) * y
        ff.append(f)

fv = np.split(np.array(ff), np.size(xx)) # split ff to make it conform with meshgrid
xv, yv = np.meshgrid(xx, yy)

plt.pcolormesh(xv, yv, fv)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

But I think the elegancy of numpy is to avoid writing loops manually and to manipulate lists as a whole. So, is there a more elegant way to do that?

Comment: If your `t0` can only solve for one set of conditions at a time, you can't avoid the loops.  "avoiding loops" in `numpy` means using `numpy` methods and operators that work with the whole arrays, for example all of ``xx` and all of `yy`.

Comment: Since `t0` only depends on `x`, you might improve performance by doing the `3**np.minum(x,2)_*t0(x)` step in one loop through `xx`.  Once you have that in an array, you can multiply it with `yy` with one broadcasted call.  `fxx[:,None]*y`.  Or at it that's too complicated, do it before you entering the `y` loop.